# LibVlc : It miss DCWRBS00176.O

Tags: c++, media, libvlc

I try to use libvlc inside my project, so i created a sample project with a few line of code :

```
libvlc_instance_t *libvlc;
libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
libvlc_media_t *m;
libvlc = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
libvlc_media_t *m = libvlc_media_new_location (libvlc, "rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554");
libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
/* Create a media player playing environement */
mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
Sleep(10000); /* Let it play a bit */
/* Stop playing */
libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);
/* Free the media_player */
libvlc_media_player_release (mp);
libvlc_release(libvlc);
```

This code compile well with with version 2.1.3 of sdk included in the VLC installer.

My problem is after compile when the program stat, an alert says :

Programm can't start,... it miss DCWRBS00176.O
If i comment out from line libvlc = libvlc_new (0, NULL); to the end, this error doesn't appear.
On time i see DCWRBS00179.O (9 not 6) by commented different lines.

I copy all dll and plugins folder in my project folder same thing...

Whats wrong ? Do i need to include something else ?

Thank you.

EDIT : With last debug version 3.0.0 from git it miss DSZBS00190.O !!!

Ps : I use embarcadero C++ XE3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found,

I was using the library included in the vlc installer, after a coff2omf the new .lib generated contains all theses dszb000xxx.o and the problems come from here.

So i used implib :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>implib -a libvlc.lib libvlc.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>implib -a libvlccore.lib libvlccore.dll
```

After linking theses libs to my project everything went fine !!!

I hope it helps someones else...